# Why does the Windows Batch script output the variable as "ECHO is off." instead of the actual value

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, script

I have written a Windows batch script to create an array and tried to print every element of the array.

However, the output is **`ECHO is off.`** instead of the actual value such as `"Apple"`.

When I changed **`ECHO is off.`** to **`@echo on`**, the result has just changed to **`ECHO is on`.**

```
@echo off
    
Rem Create variable
set fruit[0]="apple"
set fruit[1]="orange"
set fruit[2]="pear"
set fruit[3]="lemon"
    
REM x is the last index of the array
set x=3
    
REM for loop [with 0 for start, 1 for step, x for end]
FOR /L %%a in (0,1,%x%) DO (
   call set var=%%fruit[%%a]%%
   set var
   echo %var%
   call echo "Text2" 
  )
 
pause
```

The command **`call set var=%%fruit[%%a]%%`** is correct because when the command **`set var`** is run, the output can successfully show something like **`var="lemon"`**, which means the `%var%` has successfully stored the value of `"lemon"`.
However, the following command **`echo %var%`** output is **`ECHO is off.`**.

How does it happen?

The following is the batch script result capture from cmd. (`@echo off`)

```
var="apple"
ECHO is off.
"Text2"
var="orange"
ECHO is off.
"Text2"
var="pear"
ECHO is off.
"Text2"
var="lemon"
ECHO is off.
"Text2"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: *How does it happen?* Read about `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: As Akina points out, because delayedexpansion is not on, var is empty, so the command executed is `echo` which just prints what the status of echo is.

Answer (score 2):

**```
> echo /?
Displays messages, or turns command-echoing on or off. 
 
ECHO [ON | OFF] 
ECHO [message] 
 
Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting.
```**

---

The `echo` command can display messages, variables and/or messages and variables on the screen, but it can also return the current status to the `echo` command, since this is a definition for the behavior of to send (or echo) action.

To one or more commands in your script/prompt, which will not occur when set to omit them (`echo off`).

Since your variable does not have a value (at run time), your **`%variable% == ""`** (nothing, no strings/characters), so, the cmd.exe (command line interpreter) will execute the command `echo %var%` as `echo` (only).

The `echo off` however assigned to the entire script, made at the beginning of it, as soon as the command `echo noting |or| echo` is used, (as it happens in its variable with no assigned value/var to display), it will display the current status for the `echo` command, as there are no strings to display on the screen.

- For testing/debugging purposes, you can avoid these messages using:

```bat
echo. %var%
echo; %var%
echo/ %var%
echo\ %var%
echo= %var%
echo+ %var%
echo( %var%
echo[ %var%
echo: %var%
```

Since there is no value in the runtime variable, any of the above `echo *` commands returns a blank line:

---

```bat
your code... 
echo= %var%
...
```

- Returns:

```bat
var="apple"

"Text2"
var="orange"

"Text2"
var="pear"

"Text2"
var="lemon"

"Text2"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

- To set and use/access your array index items, you can use:

**[Split String Into Substrings Based on Delimiter](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)** / **[dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com)**

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_array=apple,orange,pear,lemon"

set "_array_0=%_array:,=" & set /a _i+=1 & set "_array_!_i!=%"
for /l %%i in (0 1 !_i!)do echo:_array_%%~i == "!_array_%%~i!"

%__AppDir__%TimeOut.exe /t 000000010 /nobreak | <con: endlocal
```

- Results:

```bat
_array_0 == "apple"
_array_1 == "orange"
_array_2 == "pear"
_array_3 == "lemon"
```

---

**Obs.:** It is good practice to use the **`endlocal`** when it is no longer needed.

---

- Some alternative using loops to set array/index value:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_var=apple,orange,pear,lemon" && set/a "_i=100000-100001"
for %%i in (!_var!)do set/a "_i+=1"&&>con set "_var_!_i!=%%~i"
    
for /L %%L in (00,01,0!_i!)do echo\ _var_%%~L == "!_var_%%~L!"
%__AppDir__%TimeOut.exe /t 000000010 /nobreak | <con: endlocal
```

- Results:

```bat
 _var_0 == "apple"
 _var_1 == "orange"
 _var_2 == "pear"
 _var_3 == "lemon"
```

---

Additional resources:

- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`Timeout /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem Create variable
set fruit[0]="apple"
set fruit[1]="orange"
set fruit[2]="pear"
set fruit[3]="lemon"


REM x is the last index of the array
set x=3

REM for loop (with 0 for start, 1 for step, x for end)
FOR /L %%a in (0,1,%x%) DO (
   call set var=%%fruit[%%a]%%
   set var
REM   echo %var%
   echo !var!
   call echo "Text2" 
   )
)

endlocal

pause
```

Without `enabledelayedexpansion` variable value is always equal to one at the beginning of cycle. `var` is empty before so `echo %var%` is expanded to `echo`  which prints current ECHO status.

With `enabledelayedexpansion` you can use not only `%variable%` but `!variable!` additionally. First one again provides the value at the start of a cycle whereas secopnd one provides actual value.

For to see this everything: add `SET var=zero` line immediately after `@echo off` command and execute initial batch file and my code (removing `REM` before `echo %var%`)

Comment: +1 although it would definitely be helpful to explain why. :)